# Add an onClick event to append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm dynamically creating a div. I'd like to add a onClick() event to it.

How do I add an onClick as in `<div class="something" id="btnHome" onClick="return true">` to this?

```
abc.append(
    $('<div />', { class: 'something', id: 'btnHome' })
);
```

**EDIT:**

I'm looking for an answer something like this

```
$('<div />', { class: 'something', id: 'btnHome' onClick: 'return true' })
```

Comment: `....}).on("click",function() {return true;});` or delegate like in the answer

Comment: @mplungjan: Nope. I'm looking for an answer like this `$('<div />', { class: 'something', id: 'btnHome' onClick: 'return true' })`

Comment: Not a good idea. USe jQUery now you have it. And why is it better for you to have the handler inside the brackets than outside? Tell us more WHY you want this

Comment: Because adding event handlers are better than using attributes to execute code. The best solution is to add it with delegation as shown in @Tushar s answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Event delegation is the right way to do it and @Tushar has the answer for you. But, if you were after something like this:

```
$('<div />', { class: 'something', id: 'btnHome' onClick: 'return true' })
```

Then, you may do:

```
$('<div/>', { 
    'text': 'new',
    'class': 'something',
    'id': 'btnHome'
}).on({
    'click': function() { alert ("clicked") }
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dg9ashm7/)

As [squint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/squint) suggests in one of the comments below, you could also use `click` as an attribue just like `text` or `id` as the following.

```
$('<div/>', { 
    'text': 'new',
    'class': 'something',
    'id': 'btnHome',
    'click': function() { alert ("clicked") }
});
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is that, you are adding event listener to each element created. Using event delegation, the event is only attached once for the parent.

Comment: @Tushar: That's not an *actual* problem. People just like to go around claiming it is.

Comment: @Tushar: Why? It does nothing to demonstrate the problem you claim, and in fact it puts delegate handlers on the `document`, which is arguably worse.

Comment: @Ishettyl: FYI, you can skip the `on()` and add the `click` handler as one of the attributes when creating the element. `$("<div>", {click: function() {...}, text: 'new', ...})`

Comment: This has the huge advantage that the inserted element doesn't need to have any unique identifier which you need for event delegation. Thanks for this approach, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

For dynamically added elements use parent to add event to the added elements.

```
$(staticParentSelector).on('click', '.something', function () {
    // Event Handler Code here
});
```

You can also use `document`, but this costs performance

```
$(document).on('click', '.something', function () {
    // Event Handler Code here
});
```

see jQuery Docs for [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I should place this in the second click part right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegated events so add to your jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click','#btnhome',function(){'do something here'});
```

You can use document or any other parent element that is already in the DOM

Comment: I have also read the comments and agree with what they say. It is not a good idea to add code this way. Use jquery instead.