# Javascript not firing on divs added by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My page has an ajax call every 30 seconds using the setInterval function that refreshes the contents of a table.

This table contains a single button on each row (that varies depending on another value) that has a set class and has an id set as a data attribute.

There is then another javascript call that should fire on the button being pressed. This call was working before I added the refresh functionality but now does not even fire.

```
$(function() {
    $('.workflow-play').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dostuff
```

The button is added using

```
$('#containerDiv').html('<a href="#" id="' + wfid + '" class="workflow-play"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></a>');
```

Comment: Have you heard of `event delegation`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29728269/2025923 Use this

Comment: So use `$(function() { $('#containerDiv').on("click",".workflow-play",function(e) { ... }); });`